# Почему перестало работать свойство CSS overflow-anchor?

Tags: javascript, css

Свойство позволяет задать правило прокрутки при добавлении на страницу новых элементов. Раньше все было нормально, теперь это свойство полностью игнорируется браузером, вот пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/h4Lno0jk/3/

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {

  var list = '';
  
    for (var i = 18; i < 118; i++) { 
    
    list +='<p>' + i + '</p>';
    
  }
  
    $('#list_box').append(list);

});
```

```css
* { overflow-anchor: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list_section">
  <div id="list_box">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>  
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    <p>18</p>        
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Показать еще">
</div>
```

Перейдите на страницу кода, нажмите кнопку "Показать еще", скролбар по идее должен переместится вниз при добавлении новых элементов, так как значение overflow-anchor: auto; но он остается на месте

Comment: `overflow-anchor` включен по умолчанию там где он поддерживается. _скролбар по идее должен переместится вниз при добавлении новых элементов_ - почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: Потому что оно для этого предназначено, уже работал с этим свойством

Comment: Раньше по крайней мере так было

Comment: _скролбар по идее должен переместится вниз при добавлении новых элементов_ - как раз не должен